# Why does vscode shows a red origin/master when GitHub has the proper commit?

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code

I am using vscode to commit and push my code to GitHub. After fumbling with the credentials, I finally managed to correctly push the local commit to GitHub.

In the vscode Git History tab, I see

[image]

`origin/HEAD` and `origin/master` are in red (which does not look good), on the `a836606` commit.

Looking directly on GitHub, I see that this commit is there as expected:

[image]

**Does the red color of the badges indeed suggest that something is wrong?**

Comment: I think that is just to make it clear that those are _remote_ references.

Comment: I believe eftshift0 is correct.  A lot of other Git tools employ some sort of color scheme like this to denote remote and local references.  Git Extensions for example uses nearly identical colors for the same thing.  There does not appear to be a setting to change the colors either.  Looks like Git itself even does this https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQYNB.png